# How can I increment up in Selenium POM?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm trying to select two quantities of the same item in Selenium POM by doing a for loop to increment up twice on an input tag, but my solution doesn't seem to work. How can I increment twice using POM?

Here's the file where I store my page objects:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TTPStorePage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public TTPStorePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    By size= By.id("size");
    By quantity= By.id("quantity_5cb788738ee07");
    By reset= By.className("reset_variations");
    By submit=By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']");
    By remove=By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-gtm4wp_product_id,'TS-TTP']");
    By contents=By.className("cart-contents");


    public void selectSize(int index) {
        Select drop = new Select(driver.findElement(size));
        drop.selectByIndex(index);
    }

    // The problem child.
    public void quantityItem() {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            driver.findElement(quantity).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
        }
    }

    public WebElement resetItems() {
        return driver.findElement(reset);
    }


    public WebElement submitButton() {
        return driver.findElement(submit);
    }

    public WebElement removeItem() {
        return driver.findElement(remove);
    }

    public WebElement cartContents() {
        return driver.findElement(contents);
    }

}
```

Here's the file where I store my test cases. This is where I have a majority of the problem. I'm trying to figure out how to correctly increment my items by two.

```
package SimpleProgrammer;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import resources.Base;
import pageObjects.TTPProductPage;
import pageObjects.TTPStorePage;

public class PurchaseApplication extends Base {

    @Test
    public void BuyItem() throws IOException {
        driver=initializeDriver();
        driver.get("https://simpleprogrammer.com/store/products/trust-the-process-t-shirt/");

        TTPProductPage pp= new TTPProductPage(driver);
        pp.TTPButton().click();
        TTPStorePage sp = new TTPStorePage(driver);
        sp.selectSize(4);
        // Right here
        sp.quantityItem();
    }

}
```

Comment: The quantity field is just an `INPUT`. Why don't you just set the value directly to "2"?

Comment: On the website I'm on, if I did sendKeys '2', the value would say '12'. There's already a '1' on the input field. The website I'm automating is this one: https://simpleprogrammer.com/store/t-shirts/trust-the-process/

Comment: Do a `.clear()` then `.sendKeys()`.

Comment: I got a "NoSuchElementException", which is weird since I entered the right ID.

Comment: Do you have a wait set? If not, add a waitForVisible.

Comment: Yep, even that doesn't work.

Comment: The ID is changing every time. Use the CSS selector, `input.qty`.

Comment: That worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is INPUT field just clear the input field first and then provide sendKeys with value.Please take the name attr which is unique your ID attrs is not Unique.

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.name("quantity"));
ele.clear();
ele.sendKeys("2");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked up the webpage you are trying to access. And the spinner you are trying to access in the `TTPStorePage`class by the locator `quantity` has a dynamic id. It changes every time you load the page. You have to change your locator strategy.

Try using one of the following locators for the quantity.

**Css Selector:**

```
By quantity = By.cssSelector("div.quantity > input");
```

**XPath:**

```
By quantity = By.xpath("//div[@class='quantity']/input");
```

**Also,** the in method `quantityItem` you don't need the for loop since you can set the value to directly your desired value by `sendKeys` since it is an `input` element.

**Try this**

```
public void quantityItem() {
    driver.findElement(quantity).clear();
    driver.findElement(quantity).sendKeys("3");
    //pressing up arrow twice would make the spinner value 3
}
```